# Find values inside a collection and compare value field

Tags: java, arraylist

What is the best approach to find a key value inside an object in arrayList and compare with another key and value inside another ArrayList? I think that Loop inside the two collections and transform in HashMap is not performatic...

Example:

```
public Class MyObj {

   private String myID;
   private Long myValue;
}

List<MyObj> lista1 = new ArrayList<MyObj>;
List<MyObj> lista2 = new ArrayList<MyObj>;

MyObj ob1 = new MyObj();

MyObj ob2 = new MyObj();

ob1.setMyId(1);
ob1.setMyValue(120);

ob1.setMyId(2);
ob1.setMyValue(150);

ob2.setMyId(1);
ob2.setMyValue(120);

ob2.setMyId(2);
ob2.setMyValue(180);
```

I want to compare the ob1 object with the ob2 with same id and return false if the value of anyone is different.

What is the best approach??

Thanks a Lot !

Comment: How are the lists relevant to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:- Implement `Comparable<T>` interface on the `MyObj` and override `compareTo(T o)` operation on your class. 
Read more here

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=10